# How to notify a queue in Swift (GCD)

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using GCD to notify main thread (have 2 async calls inside the function)

My code:

```
func getWavesByMostRecent(closure: @escaping ([Wave]?) -> Void) {
    var waves = [Wave]()
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    self.query = DatabaseManager.waveRef.queryOrdered(byChild: Constants.reverseTimeStampKey)
    self.handle = self.query?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for value in snapshot.children {
            guard let wave = Wave(snapshot: value as! DataSnapshot) else { return }

            self.geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: DatabaseManager.waveRef)
            let currentLocation = LocationManager.shared.getCurrentLocation()

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.geoFire?.getLocationForKey(wave.waveID, withCallback: { (location, error) in
                guard let location = location else { return }
                if error == nil {
                    if location.distance(from: currentLocation) < Constants.distance {
                        print("Wave", wave.waveID, "is in range")
                        waves.append(wave)
                    } else {
                        print("Wave", wave.waveID, "is out of range")
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("THERE ARE SO MANY WAVES:", waves.count)
            closure(waves)
        }
    })
}
```

But .notify closure just doesn't work and I cannot call my "main" closure right. What am I doing wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your `dispatchGroup.leave()` is called the same number of times with `dispatchGroup.enter()`? If not, add `print("enter")` and `print("leave")` before each of them and count the outputs of `enter` and `leave`.

Comment: It's just one .enter and one .leave, checked that

Comment: Oh, that's a loop you're right. It's 10 enter and 9 leave. But what should I do with that? @OOPer

Comment: You need to cover all possibilities. You must have a `leave` on _every_ way of exiting the completion function. (`defer` might be your friend here.)

Comment: @OOPer I found the error. There was an object without coordinates, so I had one guard to return therefore 9 leaves. Thank you so much!

Comment: Right, or you could have changed `guard let location = location else { return }` to `guard let location = location else { DispatchGroup.leave(); return }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this change:

```
self.geoFire?.getLocationForKey(wave.waveID, withCallback: { (location, error) in
    defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }
    guard let location = location else { return }
    if error == nil {
        if location.distance(from: currentLocation) < Constants.distance {
            print("Wave", wave.waveID, "is in range")
            waves.append(wave)
        } else {
            print("Wave", wave.waveID, "is out of range")
        }
    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
})
```

As noted in matt's comment `defer` is a good tool to do something always when leaving.

---

This is another issue, but updating an Array from multiple thread simultaneously would cause some problems. It rarely happens, so it can be a hard-to-fix bug.

I'm not sure if `GeoFire` calls its callback in the main thread or not, but if not, you should better enclose all the callback code in `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}`.

Answer (score -3):

dispatchGroup.leave() is still in the closure, instead it should be at the end of the for loop like this:

```
func getWavesByMostRecent(closure: @escaping ([Wave]?) -> Void) {
    var waves = [Wave]()
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    self.query = DatabaseManager.waveRef.queryOrdered(byChild: Constants.reverseTimeStampKey)
    self.handle = self.query?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for value in snapshot.children {
            guard let wave = Wave(snapshot: value as! DataSnapshot) else { return }

            self.geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: DatabaseManager.waveRef)
            let currentLocation = LocationManager.shared.getCurrentLocation()

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.geoFire?.getLocationForKey(wave.waveID, withCallback: { (location, error) in
                guard let location = location else { return }
                if error == nil {
                    if location.distance(from: currentLocation) < Constants.distance {
                        print("Wave", wave.waveID, "is in range")
                        waves.append(wave)
                    } else {
                        print("Wave", wave.waveID, "is out of range")
                    }
                } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                }
            })
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("THERE ARE SO MANY WAVES:", waves.count)
            closure(waves)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: according to Ray Wenderlich it should be inside https://www.raywenderlich.com/148515/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-2

Comment: This is a ridiculous change. `dispatchGroup.leave()` may be called **before** the completion handler finishes.

Comment: You do not understand "asynchronous".

Comment: @OOPer not *may*, *will*.